# Difference between Ale and Bitter

Tags: ale

Whats the difference between a bitter and an Ale? Is it the manufacturing process or the ingredients that make these different drinks?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Bitters *are* ales; the English term *bitter* is generally equivalent to *pale ale*.  Pale ales are made from pale malt and many types are heavily hopped.  The term *bitter* refers to the bitterness inherent in their hoppy character when compared to other beers like stouts and porters.

Note that like many beer terms, taxonomy is not hard and fast, e.g. a blonde could be considered a pale ale but few would refer to it as a bitter!